# Order elements in data frame based on their appearance

Tags: r, dataframe

Let me take a data frame like:

```
>df : Col_1   Col_2  Col_3
       A       B       z
       C       D       x
       A       D       c
       B       A       g
       D       C       f
```

Now, I need to order df like this:

```
>df1 : Col_1   Col_2  Col_3
        A       B      z
        C       D      x
        A       D      c
        A       B      g
        C       D      f
```

So, I need to arrange this data frame with order of their occurence in the 1st attempt(here in df we have A,B in row-1 and B,A in row-4. 
I want to arrange them as A,B in row-1 and A,B in row-4 as shown in df1)

Comment: The logic is unclear. Why do you also rearrange row 5 but leave the others unchanged?

Comment: I think because the combination C and D was found before as well

Comment: so row 2 = C D, thus, row 5 entries should be swapped to match row2

Comment: another option `t(apply(data, 1, function(x) c(x[1:2][order(x[1:2])], x[3])))`

Comment: @VeerendraGadekar you can shorten that to: `t(apply(mydf[1:2], 1, function(x) x[order(x)]))` imo

Comment: You both assume that the first occurrences are ordered for some reason. This won't work for `df[1, -3] <- c("B", "A")`

Comment: @DavidArenburg I don't assume that and it also works when changing the initial data as you proposed.

Comment: @Jaap, no. It will reorder the first row too.

Comment: I've updated my answer. HTH

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After re-reading the question (after @DavidArenburg's comment), a possible solution:

```
# order the letters rowwise in alphabetical order and paste them together in a character vector
x <- do.call(paste0, data.frame(t(apply(mydf[1:2], 1, function(x) x[order(x)]))))
# create an index for the first occurance
idx <- as.integer(factor(x, levels = unique(x)))
# replace with the first occurance
mydf[,-3] <- mydf[idx,-3]
```

which gives:

```
> mydf
  Col_1 Col_2 Col_3
1     B     A     z
2     C     D     x
3     A     D     c
4     B     A     g
5     C     D     f
```

---

Used data:

```
mydf <- structure(list(Col_1 = structure(c(2L,3L,1L,2L,4L), .Label = c("A","B","C","D"), class = "factor"), 
                       Col_2 = structure(c(1L,4L,4L,1L,3L), .Label = c("A","B","C","D"), class = "factor"), 
                       Col_3 = structure(c(5L,4L,1L,3L,2L), .Label = c("c","f","g","x","z"), class = "factor")), 
                  .Names = c("Col_1","Col_2","Col_3"), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```

---

**Old answer:** You could create an index of the rows in which the letter in `Col_1` is of a higher order than in `Col_2` and then just swap the two values:

```
# create a match vector
ltrs <- setNames(LETTERS,1:26)

# create an index for which rows the letter in 'Col_1' is of a higher order than in 'Col_2'
idx <- match(mydf$Col_1, ltrs) > match(mydf$Col_2, ltrs)

# swap the two values
mydf[idx,-3] <- mydf[idx, c(2,1)]
```

which gives:

```
> mydf
  Col_1 Col_2 Col_3
1     A     B     z
2     C     D     x
3     A     D     c
4     A     B     g
5     C     D     f
```